# Array method from user input

Tags: java, arrays

So as you might be able to see I tried making a method for user input that takes first two elements and averages them and then the middle elements are taken averages by `signal[i-1]`, `signal[i]`, and `signal[i+1]` then the last two numbers are also averages but as you can see I'm way off.

```java
 import  java.util.Scanner;
    public class Radio
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How many values will you enter: ");
        int a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter in the sampled signals values with spaces      imbetween");
        double[] signal = new double[a];
        for (int i=0; i<signal.length; i++)
        {
            signal[i]=input.nextInt();
        }
        double[] result = smooth(signal);
        System.out.println("Smoothed Values: ");
        for (double b : result)
        {
            System.out.print(b + " ");
        }
    }
    public static double[] smooth(double[] signal)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < signal.length; i++)
        {
        result[i-1]=signal[i];
        result[Average i] = signal[i];
        result[Average i+1]=signal[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: *but as you can see I'm way off* I'm sorry but it's actually not directly obvious to me. Do you get an error? Not desired output? If so please post the full stacktrace/desired and current output. (Or in other words, please provide an [MCVE])

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: What is the line `result[Average i] = signal[i];` supposed to do?

Comment: when `i == 0` what do you think will happen with `result[i-1]=signal[i];`

Comment: It is just a huge error and the line is supposed to take elements from signal take average i - 1 of elements and store in result

Comment: John, the point of my comment is that `result [0 - 1]` i.e. `result [-1]` is not valid

Comment: You should also instantiate your `result` variable in your `smooth` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. First take the average of the first two, then iterate over the middle part and then take the average of the last two. Like so:

```
public static double[] smooth(double[] signal)
    {
        int[] = result = new int[signal.length - 1];
        result[0] = (signal[0] + signal[1]) / 2;
        for(int i = 1; i < signal.length - 1; i++)
        {
            result[i] = (signal[i - 1] + signal[i] + signal[i + 1]) / 3;
        }
        result[signal.length - 1] = (signal[signal.length - 2] + signal[signal.length - 1]) / 2;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: @John Humphrey: Is this indeed what you are after?

Comment: Sorry I just got to this and thank you so much this was a majority of it but I finally figure it out